# No folders in Hadoop 2.6 after installing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig, hdfs, bigdata

I am new to Hadoop. I succesfully installed hadoop 2.6 in my Ubuntu 12.04 by follwing the below link.

[Hadoop 2.6 Installation](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php)

All services are running. But when I try to load file from local to HDFS, but it not at all showing folders in HDFS like /user or /data

```
hduse@vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p:~$ jps
4163 SecondaryNameNode
4374 ResourceManager
3783 DataNode
3447 NameNode
5048 RunJar
18538 Jps
4717 NodeManager

hduse@vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p:~$ hadoop version
Hadoop 2.6.0
Subversion https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r e3496499ecb8d220fba99dc5ed4c99c8f9e33bb1
Compiled by jenkins on 2014-11-13T21:10Z
Compiled with protoc 2.5.0
From source with checksum 18e43357c8f927c0695f1e9522859d6a
This command was run using /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.6.0.jar

hduse@vijee-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p:~$ hadoop fs -ls hdfs:/
No output
```

If I run the above command: hadoop fs -ls hdfs:/, it is not showing any folder.  I installed Pig as well and now I want to load data to Pig in mapreduce mode. In most of the websites they mentioned blindly URI in place of HDFS path. Please guide how to create folders and load data in the hdfs path.

Comment: Could you please provide the log from the namenode format command

Answer (score 2):

If you are using plain vanilla hadoop, you will not see any directories. You have to create those.

You can start creating by running `hadoop fs -mkdir /user`